# How is Display "cleaner" than Debug?

Tags: rust

In the [Display](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/hello/print/print_display.html) chapter of Rust By Example, it describes `Display` as "cleaner" than `Debug`.

> `fmt::Debug` hardly looks compact and clean ...
>
> `fmt::Display` may be cleaner than `fmt::Debug` but ...

How is this? From what I see, you have to do more work and write more code to try and make `Display` work while `Debug` works right off the bat! Am I misunderstanding something about what "cleaner code" is, or is this a typo?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Display's **output** is usually cleaner than Debug's, not the code to implement it. Debug's output is intended to be used for debug purposes, providing a less ambiguous output. Display's output is for user-facing output, so it's highly dependent on the meaning of your structure and that's why it cannot be derived.

For example, consider the following code:

```
fn main() {
    // Note that \t is the TAB character
    let output = "N\tO\tI\tC\tE";
    println!("Debug: {:?}", output);
    println!("Display: {}", output);
}
```

It will output:

```
Debug: "N\tO\tI\tC\tE"
Display: N  O   I   C   E
```

In this case, Debug will show the characters that the str (text) contains (as its more useful when debugging), while Display will just print them.